# CSS @import from external server like get query

Tags: php, css

I have spent the past few days but I can not find a solution.

I try to import an external CSS directly from the CSS file using @import rule like this:

```
@import url(http://myanothersite.com/styles.php?style=1);
```

I need my external site using a php script gave the desired style depending on get request. But the problem is that the external site with the script does not give any style line.
Maybe someone knows how to solve this problem.

Something similar had seen with fonts from Google, there is a script

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400&subset=latin
```

and result is

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Ubuntu';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
src: local('Ubuntu'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ubuntu/v8/sDGTilo5QRsfWu6Yc11AXg.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "a style line"?

Comment: Does `http://myanothersite.com/styles.php?style=1` (the proper URL) work as expected when accessed directly?

Comment: http://myanothersite.com/ itself is not working.

Comment: example php script deicide to give style for `span { background-color: #f5f5f5; }` but site whene I use @import rule it does not get style for this tag

Comment: when i access directly in browser I get the result but when i using @import from css file it`s not work

Comment: @Snowman Try adding the `header("Content-type: text/css");` to styles.php as @Tibor B. answered below, otherwise post the contents of styles.php

Comment: Please see my answer. You have to set your PHP file to have a content type of CSS, and it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the content type of your PHP file to CSS. Just simply place the following line on the top of your PHP code:

```
header("Content-type: text/css");
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about the heather and looking for a solution more complex ways

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help.